# change color PNG Image QPushbutton

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I tried to change a color of my PNG image after set its color by QtWidgets.QColorDialog. with Python

[image]

---> to

[image]

Nevertheless, when I apply my code the result is :

[image]

It change the background of my PNG image

The png source is here: DMX_Led

[image]

I write a small sample of my code :

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

class Ui_MainWindows(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_MainWindows,self).__init__()
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Change color PNG Test")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:black;")
        self.resize(350, 350)
        self.DMX_Color = QtGui.QColor('#000000')
        self.button_DMX = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
        print("Add ")
        path_image = os.path.join(dir_path,"Ressource/Rampe3.png").replace("\\", "/")
        qss = 'border-image: url({})'.format(path_image)
        self.button_DMX.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 61)
        self.button_DMX.setStyleSheet(qss)
        self.button_DMX.clicked.connect(self.processButton_DMX)

    def processButton_DMX(self):
        print("Projector DMX clicked ")

        self.DMX_Color.setRed(0)
        self.DMX_Color.setGreen(0)
        self.DMX_Color.setBlue(255)
        print("Change Color Button DMX")
        effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsColorizeEffect(self.button_DMX)
        effect.setColor(self.DMX_Color)
        self.button_DMX.setGraphicsEffect(effect)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Ui_MainWindows()
    MainWindow.show()

    rc = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(rc)


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QGraphicsEffect` are applied to transparent pixels so it is not the best option, a possible solution is to work with a `QImage` and set it as an icon by applying the pixel to pixel colors change:

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

class Ui_MainWindows(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_MainWindows,self).__init__()
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Change color PNG Test")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:black;")
        self.resize(350, 350)

        self.DMX_Color = QtGui.QColor('#000000')
        self.button_DMX = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
        self.button_DMX.move(100, 100)
        path_image = os.path.join(dir_path, "Ressource/Rampe3.png").replace("\\", "/")
        self.image = QtGui.QImage(path_image)

        self.button_DMX.clicked.connect(self.processButton_DMX)
        self.change_image()

    def change_image(self, color=QtGui.QColor("white")):
        for x in range(self.image.width()):
            for y in range(self.image.height()):
                pcolor = self.image.pixelColor(x, y)
                if pcolor.alpha() > 0:
                    n_color = QtGui.QColor(color)
                    n_color.setAlpha(pcolor.alpha())
                    self.image.setPixelColor(x, y, n_color)
        self.button_DMX.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.image)))
        self.button_DMX.setIconSize(self.image.size())
        self.button_DMX.setFixedSize(self.image.size())        

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def processButton_DMX(self):
        color = QtWidgets.QColorDialog.getColor(QtCore.Qt.white, self)
        if color.isValid():
            self.change_image(color)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Ui_MainWindows()
    MainWindow.show()

    rc = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(rc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```